# How to change color of the custom side of border?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I want to make visible just bottom border of TextView. How can I do it?

Can I make visible just bottom side of the textView or there are another method?

Answer (score 1):

You can add layer for your aim, but I'm not sure that is right way.

```
+ (void)addBottomBorderToView: (UIView * ) view WithColor:(UIColor *)color andWidth:(CGFloat) borderWidth
{
    CALayer * bottomBorder = [CALayer layer];
    bottomBorder.borderColor = color.CGColor;
    bottomBorder.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, view.frame.size.height - borderWidth, view.frame.size.width, borderWidth);
    [view.layer addSublayer:bottomBorder];
}
```